# Sitecore Indexing with Lucene

Tags: indexing, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

How can I test if some fields are indexed in Sitecore. The project uses Lucene. For developers I believe this is easy but I´m not a developer, any idea or help will help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There is tool called Luke that can open Lucene indexes for you (https://code.google.com/archive/p/luke/) but not sure if that will do what you want.

Comment: In my sitecore project, some pages have some products with the field ID and NAME, and this fields need to be indexed in Lucene, I will try this Luke, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can try building/rebuilding indices using Control Panel of Sitecore.

- Login to sitecore > Sitecore Experience Manager. Go to Control Panel.
- Go to INDEXING section and click on 'Indexing manager'
- A modal dialog showing different indices will open.
- Select indices and click on Rebuild

Rebuilding indices will always build latest modifications in content. Hope this helps.

[Control panel of sitecore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QEmy.png)
[Indexing Manager dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7pD7.png)